# about string removing in C#

Tags: c#, .net, string

Whats is correct to do?

check if exists, then remove?

```
var input = "foo #main baa"; 
if(input.Contains("#main")) {
   input = input.Replace("#main", "");
}
```

or just:

```
input = input.Replace("#main", "");
```

Well, this seem a simple question,but I really want know.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Contains` check actually just makes your code *slower*.
Remove it.

The `Contains` call needs to loop through the string until it finds `#main`.
The `Replace` call then needs to do the same exact loop (it can't remember it from the `Contains` call).
This is a [Shlemiel the Painter's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlemiel_the_Painter%27s_algorithm).

`Replace` can handle strings with zero or more occurrences of the search string, so you don't need the check.

Answer (score 4):

Just do the replacement - if it's not there, nothing should happen.

Answer (score 1):

Just make the call to `Replace()`.  If the substring isn't found nothing happens and you avoid an additional call to `Contains()`.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
input = input.Replace("#main", "").Replace("  "," ");
```

To remove any double spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove it. The only thing to check is if the string is null or not.